# How to set up my model-relations properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relation

I have 3 models: Hacks, Votes, Users.

A user can create many hacks.
Each user should be able to vote on each hack ONCE (Rating of 1-5. Rating should be updateable in case of a missclick or whatever).

I thought about the following relations:
Hack.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

User.rb

```
has_many :hacks
```

Votes.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :hack
```

Is that correct or am I missing something?
I thought about getting all the votes like this later on:

```
Hack.first.votes
```

What kind of foreign-keys do I have to set up?
In my schema.rb I already successfully set my users<=>hack relation up, without any foreign keys.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20141019161631) do

  create_table "hacks", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "url"
    t.string   "name"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",            null: false
    t.string   "crypted_password", null: false
    t.string   "salt",             null: false
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "role"
  end

end
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to have.

```
class User.rb
  has_many :votes
  has_many :hacks, through: :votes
end

class Vote.rb
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hack
end

class Hack.rb
  has_many :votes
end
```

With this, a hack has many votes through a user.

foreign keys:
votes table: user_id, hack_id

You should be able to do hack.votes

EDIT:

I edited the model to reflect a normal has many through relationship

user -> vote <- hack

a user has many votes
a user has many hacks through votes
a hack has many votes

foreign keys live in the votes table. You can use the following when creating the votes table to indicate the foreign key

```
t.references user
t.references hack
```

Comment: Thank you very much. These relations do sound reasonable. Do you know if Rails requires me to set these foreign columns manually or if the belongs_to/has_many roptions do that for me?

Comment: I found a mistake. With your answer a hack has_many users but ONE hack should only be assigned to ONE user. ONE user however, can create MANY hacks.

That would mean
User has_many :hacks.
User has_many :votes
Hack belongs_to :user
Hack has_many :votes through: :users